Probability that a sequence has any(!) element that is repeated exactly $k$ times
I want to calculate the probability that in a sequence of $n$ random events, one or more of the possible outcomes is repeated exactly $k$ times, in any order. Crucially, I don't care about which outcome is repeated and I don't care if one, two, or more outcomes are repeated $k$ times. All I'm interested in is whether my sequence contains any repetition of an element with $k$ repetitions.
For example, let's assume that I'm looking at sequences with four elements. Each element is drawn with replacement from $X = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ with $p=1/5$ for each outcome. For $k=3$, I want to know the probability of sequences like $[1, 1, 1, 2]$, $[2, 5, 2, 2]$, $[1, 4, 4, 4], \ldots$, which all contain one element that is repeated $k=3$ times. For $k=2$, I'm interested in the probability of sequences $[1, 1, 2, 3]$, $[1, 3, 2, 3]$, $[4, 5, 5, 4], \ldots$ Again, each sequence contains at least one element that is repeated $k=2$ times. The fact that the last sequence has two elements ($4$ and $5$) that are each repeated $2$ times isn't relevant for my purposes; this sequence should count as just one "success" when determining the probabilities.
Background: I'm developing a little puzzle game that generates the solutions as sequences of four elements drawn randomly from a pool of five possible answers (with replacement). During testing, I noticed that solutions in which one of the five possible answers was repeated three times occurred much more frequently than my naive brain would have expected, and my first thought was that there was an error in my game. I know that people are generally bad at assessing the likelihood of random events, so I eventually forced myself to trust the random number generator and my algorithm after all. But still, I wanted to find out how probable repetitious sequences like this actually are.
I've written a small Python script to simulate the probabilities. Here's the outcome for 1,000,000 simulation runs (the script is provided at the end of this question) for $n=4$ with five possible outcomes:
p(k=1) = 0.19103
p(k=2) = 0.67266
p(k=3) = 0.12824
p(k=4) = 0.00807

This suggests that in 12.8 percent of the sequences, one of the five possible outcomes was repeated 3 times, and in 67.3 percent of all sequences, at least one of the outcomes occurred exactly two times. As expected, sequences with only one outcome are rare (0.8 percent). Perhaps somewhat unexpectedly, sequences with no repetition are not much more frequent than sequences with an element that is repeated three times.
To calculate these probabilities numerically, my first idea was that I could just start with the probability function of the binomial distribution, which gives me for a given outcome with probability $p$ exactly $k$ times in a sequence of $n$ elements:
$$
P(n, k) = {n \choose k } \times p^k \times (1-p)^{(n-k)}
$$
My logic was that since I don't care which of the five possible outcomes is repeated $k$ times, all I'd have to do is multiply $P(n, k)$ by $5$. As demonstrated below, this actually works for $k>2$. But there's flaw in this logic for cases where the repetitions are shorter than the sequence. For $k=2$, the sequences containing two repetitions like $[1, 5, 5, 1]$ are considered twice when calculating $P(n, 2$) (once for the outcome $1$, once for the outcome $5$), but as explained above, that's not what I want: any sequence in which any element occurs more than once should be considered as a "success" as far as the calculation of the probability of $k$ repetitions is concerned, regardless of how many $k$ repetitions that sequence contains.
As expected, the result of my first attempt agree with my Python simulation for $k=3$ and $k=4$, but they are obviously implausible for $k=1$ and $k=2$:

$k = 1: P(4, 1) \times 5 = 2.048$
$k = 2: P(4, 2) \times 5 = 0.768$
$k = 3: P(4, 3) \times 5 = 0.128$
$k = 2: P(4, 4) \times 5 = 0.008$

So, what is the right way of calculating the probability that a sequence of $n$ elements contains one or more elements that are repeated exactly $k$ times in that sequence?

Here is my Python script that I used to obtain the simulated probabilities:
from random import choice
from collections import Counter

MAX_RUNS = 1000000
OUTCOMES = range(5)
N = 4

def main():
    repetition_counter = Counter()
    for _ in range(MAX_RUNS):
        # count the number of each outcomes for the current simulation run:
        outcome_counter = Counter([choice(OUTCOMES) for _ in range(N)])

        # the next line deliberately ignores cases where a sequence contains
        # more than one element that is repeated several times:
        max_k = outcome_counter.most_common()[0][1]
        repetition_counter[max_k] += 1

    for k in range(N):
        print(f"p(k={k+1}) = {repetition_counter[k+1] / MAX_RUNS:1.5f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I do not see how you get p(k=1) = 0.19103 as the simulated probability that when selecting four values you have at least one of the five possible values appearing exactly one time.  I think it should be substantially higher at $1-\frac{{5 \choose 1}{4 \choose 4}+{5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}}{5^4}=0.896$, since the only way to avoid it happening is to have all four the same or two of one possible value and two of another.

You search : probability that at least 1 element is repeated exactly $k$ times. Very often, when we have 'at last' in the question, it is more simple to search for the opposit : probability that no element is repeated exactly $k$ times.

@Henry: My simulation code may be buggy, but it's so simple that I can't see where a bug might hide actually. Plus: Shouldn't the simulated probabilities add up to 1.0 since the four cases $k=1$, $k=2$, $k=3$, $k=4$ are mutually exclusive, and cover all possible outcomes? Then, $p(k=1) = 1.0 - p(k=2) - p(k=3) - p(k=4)$, and since your answer provides the right-hand probabilities, it would follow that $p(k=1) = 1.0 - 0.672 - 0.128 - 0.008 = 0.192$, which is pretty close to my simulated probability.

@Schmuddi I do not think, as worded, your question makes the case of $k=1$ and $k=3$ mutually exclusive.  With your example sequence of $[1,1,1,2]$ I see $1$ occurring exactly $3$ times so $k=3$, while $2$ occurs exactly $1$ time so $k=1$.  Similarly the sequence $[1,3,2,3]$ has both $1$ and $2$ each occurring exactly $1$ time so is an example of $k=1$ (as well as an example of $k=2$ as $3$ occurs exactly $2$ times).

The $k=2$ result can be calculated directly, by considering both the case of two appearances of one possible value and two appearances of another, and the case of two of one possible value and one each of two others, which would be $\frac{{5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}+{5 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}}{5^4} = \frac{60+360}{625}=0.672$.
I do not see how you got p(k=1) = 0.19103 as the simulated probability that when selecting four values you have at least one of the five possible values appearing exactly one time. I think it should be substantially higher at $1-\frac{{5 \choose 1}{4 \choose 4}+{5 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}}{5^4}=0.896$, since the only way to avoid it happening is to have all four the same or two of one possible value and two of another.
More generally, let's assume each of the $n$ values in the sequence is independently equally likely to be any of the $m$ possible values, so the probability of each possible sequence is $\frac{1}{m^n}$, and let's call the probability that any value appears exactly $k$ times is $Q(n,k,m)$.
Then you can say that for any particular possible value, either it appears exactly $k$ times and the others do not, or one of the other values appears exactly $k$ times, so
$$Q(n,k,m) = {n \choose k}\frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n} (1-Q(n-k,k,m-1)) \\ \qquad \qquad +  \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}\frac{(m-1)^{n-i}}{m^n} Q(n-i,k,m-1)$$ and, if you prefer, you can write ${n \choose k}\frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n}$ as $P_m(n,k)$ and ${n \choose i}\frac{(m-1)^{n-i}}{m^n}$ as $P_m(n,i)$.
You start with $Q(n,k,m)=0$ for $n<k$, $Q(k,k,1)=1$, and $Q(n,k,1)=0$ for $n \not= k$.
It is easy enough to code this recurrence, for example in R
Q <- function(maxn, k, maxm){
  matq <- matrix(0, ncol=maxm, nrow=maxn+1) # R starts counting at 1
  matq[k+1, 1] <- 1
  for (m in 2:maxm){
    for (n in k:maxn){
      matq[n+1, m] <- dbinom(k,n,1/m) * (1 - matq[n-k+1, m-1]) + 
                   sum(dbinom(0:n,n,1/m) * matq[n-(0:n)+1, m-1])
      }
    }
  rownames(matq) <- paste("n=", 0:maxn, sep="")
  colnames(matq) <- paste("m=", 1:maxm, sep="")
  return(matq)
  }

which gives, for $k=0:$
> Q(4,0,5)   
    m=1   m=2       m=3     m=4 m=5
n=0   1 1.000 1.0000000 1.00000   1
n=1   0 1.000 1.0000000 1.00000   1
n=2   0 0.500 1.0000000 1.00000   1
n=3   0 0.250 0.7777778 1.00000   1
n=4   0 0.125 0.5555556 0.90625   1

for $k=1:$
> Q(4,1,5)   
    m=1  m=2       m=3     m=4   m=5
n=0   0 0.00 0.0000000 0.00000 0.000
n=1   1 1.00 1.0000000 1.00000 1.000
n=2   0 0.50 0.6666667 0.75000 0.800
n=3   0 0.75 0.8888889 0.93750 0.960
n=4   0 0.50 0.7407407 0.84375 0.896

for $k=2:$
> Q(4,2,5)
    m=1   m=2       m=3      m=4   m=5
n=0   0 0.000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000
n=1   0 0.000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000
n=2   1 0.500 0.3333333 0.250000 0.200
n=3   0 0.750 0.6666667 0.562500 0.480
n=4   0 0.375 0.6666667 0.703125 0.672

for $k=3:$
> Q(4,3,5)
    m=1  m=2       m=3    m=4   m=5
n=0   0 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000 0.000
n=1   0 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000 0.000
n=2   0 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000 0.000
n=3   1 0.25 0.1111111 0.0625 0.040
n=4   0 0.50 0.2962963 0.1875 0.128

and for $k=4:$
> Q(4,4,5) 
    m=1   m=2        m=3      m=4   m=5
n=0   0 0.000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000
n=1   0 0.000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000
n=2   0 0.000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000
n=3   0 0.000 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000
n=4   1 0.125 0.03703704 0.015625 0.008

The bottom right numbers (i.e. when $n=4, m=5$) of the last three of these fit your simulated results.

As far as $k=1$ goes, you say "since the only way to avoid it happening is to have all four the same or two of one possible value and two of another". I'm afraid that I can't quite follow. I would consider $k=1$ to be the case where each value of the sequence is unique (the highest number of repetitions of any element is $1$). The first situation that you describe ("have all four the same") would be $k=4$, and "two of one possible value" would be $k=2$. Does that make sense?

@Schmuddi - You say "one or more of the possible outcomes is repeated exactly $k$ times" so implying for example that one of one value and three of another would satisify both $k=1$ and $k=3$.  If you are saying that you only want the frequency of the most common occurrence, then I would have thought that would be a different question; it would be closer to your simulation as with $n=4$ and $m=5$, the probability of all four being different would be $\frac{120}{625}=0.192$.  That question about the distribution of the frequency of the most common occurrence has been asked before here.
